# Tilt table test and beta blockers

Tags: medications, brain, neurology, test, beta-blockers

Is [tilt table test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt_table_test) indicative with beta blockers for dysautonomia diagnosis? Or is it require drug withdrawal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if a tilt table test can be conducted while the patient is taking beta blockers?

Comment: I was instructed to taper off of beta blockers for a minimum of three weeks prior to autonomic testing. It dampens the heart rate accelerations, so it could produce a false negative as I understand it. That's what I was told and had to do for the testing.

Comment: @Lilibete Thanks for that info!

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, it is about “how true are the test results with regular beta blockers taking”. Sorry for my English